# Font Family not applied on mobile

Tags: css

I hav defined the font-family in the body tag in css. When inspected, the mobile view seems to work but when hosted and opened in a mobile it's not workin

CSS Code:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif !important;
}
```

[image: Inspect, mobile view]
Inspect Mobile View

[image: Real Mobile]Real Mobile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Font Family must exist on device to be used. Your PC has that font, while Mobile does not.

You can always add fonts sources from [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/), [fontsquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/) or embedded from own source:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FooBar';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(/fonts/FooBar.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

---

Georgia is not free font, that's why it's not on any open-source fonts platform.

Comment: @kd12345 You must also source these files, not just place in storage

Comment: yes after i stored then on firebase storage, i am sourcing them in my index.css